# Count Specific Rows in A Datagrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

I know this will give you a total row count `int rowCount = myGrid.Items.Count;` but I am after a count of each `Location` in the grid.  For example, my sample data structure is like so, and I need a count of each location in the grid:

```
Location --- Assigned
F            Red
F            Red
F            Red
F            Red
R            Blue
R            Blue
L            Green
```

And my desired count would be F = 4, R = 2, L = 1